# What do you call a photo like your passport or ID photo?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Headshot" sounds too informal. I'm referring to the serious photo that we take for passport or ID card. What's the best word to describe it?  I need to a term to describe the type of photo but I'm not using them for passport.

Photo ID? Facial Photo?

Comment: 'Passport photo' is a broadened term; I have one on my bus pass.

Comment: "ID photo" would probably work; "ID or passport photo" is probably the most descriptive though. There isn't a shorter word/phrase for this that I'm aware of.

Comment: A passport photo is a passport photo, whether you put it in a passport or not. Just like leg warmers stay leg warmers even if you wear them as a hat, and a dog buiscuit stays a dog buiscuit whether you eat it yourself or feed it to your child.

Comment: "Terrible" is the usual characterization.

Comment: I think *headshot* is exactly the term a photographer would use.

Answer (score 3):

Informally, this sort of photograph is called a **mugshot**:

> 1 *informal* A photograph of a person's face made for an official purpose, especially police records.
>
> > ‘when shown mugshots, the victim was unable to recognize anyone’
>
> 1.1 *humorous* Any photograph of a person's face.
>
> > ‘a mugshot on the book's cover shows the author’
>
> [Lexico from Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mugshot)

*Mug* is slang for face (as [Lexico shows](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mug)), but even OED is unclear why; it suggests an allusion to Toby jugs, “the drinking mugs made to represent a grotesque human face which were common in the 18th cent.”

Comment: Stereotypical mugshots include two photos, one in profile.

Comment: No, they really don't. But if they do, then **each one of those** is a mugshot. (Source: Metropolitan Police, London)

Comment: Well perhaps I should have said that mugshots usually come in pairs, including one in profile. That is, "mugshot" is a broader category than what the OP asked about.

Comment: But if _headshot_ is too informal, then _mugshot_ is surely even more so?

Answer (score 2):

"Photo ID" would be the whole document (ie a passport or driving licence). In the UK they are usually called "passport photo".

Comment: How about facial photo? I need to a term to describe the type of photo but I'm not using them for passport.

Comment: That doesn't matter: it's a passport photo, regardless of what you use it for.

Answer (score 1):

The type of picture used in passports and on other types of photo ID, such as driving licences ('licenses' in USA), identity cards, etc, is often called a 'head and shoulders' portrait.

> (c) Each individual identification card shall contain the name of the
>   individual to whom it was issued, his or her date of birth, the class
>   of license, the category or categories to which he or she is licensed,
>   and a head and shoulders picture (passport type) taken within three
>   (3) months prior to the date of issuance of the license.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a shampoo to me...lol! But not sure if I can use that on a website. "Please upload your 'head and shoulders' photo." Will they upload a bottle of shampoo, instead?! Kidding...lol!

Comment: Commonly used in many English-speaking countries, since before the shampoo brand was created.

Comment: "Passport photos"  are a very specific subset of "head and shoulders photos". A proper "head and shoulders portrait" would not be acceptable as a passport photo because it would have complex modelling lighting, the subject would usually be smiling, the background would be lit unevenly and the aspect may well be three quarter rather than square on to the camera.

Answer (score -1):

There are specialized cameras called "Photo I.D. cameras", so I would call them "photo I.D. images".

https://www.idzone.com/CCam.html

The product is called "Credential Cam Photo ID Camera".